# Converting a char array to string using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

```
date         time        machine     power    energy    heat
?            ?           ?           MW       kJ        kJ
2/15/2016    20:50:46    kuka        45       22        22
2/15/2016    20:50:47    kuka        50       24        22
2/15/2016    20:50:48    kuka        56       26        22
2/15/2016    20:50:49    kuka        58       28        22
2/15/2016    20:50:50    kuka        62       30        22
2/15/2016    20:50:51    kuka        60       32        22
2/15/2016    20:50:52    kuka        64       34        20
```

I have a textfile and I imported data using `importdata()` command in matlab

I have tried `Delimiter` with space `' '` and `'\t'`

All data is saved in a `struct` as fine I as need but the problem is in the first line all of it is saved in one cell like  `date  time  machine  power  energy  heat`

All of the other data like `?` , `MW` , `KJ` and `45` are save in separate cells which are fine.

I want data from the first row as separate entities like `data` `time` `machine` etc

If I save that cell in a variable name `X` then output is like `'date  time  machine  power  energy  heat'`

When I check `class` of this its `char`

What I want know is to convert this `char` to a `string` so that I can continue writing code for my GUI

Comment: [`String == Character array`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strings.html) in MATLAB, (but you also have [cell arrays of strings](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellstr.html)).

Comment: You can probably design a class names `string` and use that one, but I would not recommend it to anyone who actually want his code to work well (someone may have done it since he thought it prettier , but this person have likely paid the price in blood). Matlab have a lot of functions which deals with "cell arrays of strings". And writing a custom string clase would not only be slow, but also force you to rewrite all functions handling strings as char arrays (and also "cell array of strings").

Comment: Cell Array are much better for handling Strings and it is more memory efficient than multiple Char Arrays.

Comment: What should I do to save `date` `time` and `machine` etc to store in separate variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering after your comment

```
d = X{1}
```

Take any variable like `Z` use `textscan` to get your desired result

```
Z = textscan(d , '%s');
```

This will make `Z` a `cell` of  order `(1 X 1)`
`Z{1}(1)` will be `date`
`Z{1}(2)` will be `time`
`Z{1}(3)` will be `machine`
......